# Transfer Symfony2 website to localhost not working

Tags: symfony

I followed three steps in transferring this site to localhost.

1. I downloaded the Symfony2 folder to my localhost.
2. I exported the live database and imported it into my local database.
3. I changed the database settings in parameters file

On the live server I use the URL: `http://myserver.com/web.`
When I go to `http://localhost/web` I get an empty page (even the source is completely empty).

Does anyone know what goes wrong?

Comment: It could be literally 100 different things. You should provide more info, eg. server type (Apache/PHP/MySQL + OS of both remote and local), Symfony version, whether `app/console` works from the commandline etc.

Comment: Let's try to setup your permissions: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup. Additionaly you should try to run your app in `dev` mode eg.: `http://localhost/web/app_dev.php`. Moreover, probably you shoul configure your `virtualHost`.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is most likely related to symfony's cache if you just downloaded the folder from upstream.

Remove everything in the `app/cache` folder using

```
rm -rf app/cache/*
```

Further monitor your webserver, php and symfony's logfiles for errors if the problem is not being resolved by clearing the cache.